# what is clock recovery?

Tags: sockets, networking, encoding

Can't find much relevant information on google.. so if anyone willing to explain me the follow questions will  be appreciated!
what exactly clock recovery is(how does it work), and why NRZ having trouble with clock recovery?

Answer (score 2):

> Can't find much relevant information on google

How hard did you try?

Here are some starting points:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero

There are many methods of doing clock recovery. The reason NRZ "has trouble" with clock recovery is because there are not transitions on the signal if there are long strings of 1's or 0's.

Comment: ha. i was mistakenly believed clock recovery was something about CRC...and couldn't understand how it is related to the circut and signaling.

Comment: why no transition hurts? i was reading about 4B/5B encoding, and it gives no more than 3 consecutive 0s and using NRZI encoding will solve the problem. Why can't 3 consecutive 0s cause clock drift...?